# SSRS report shared data source wont render

Tags: reporting-services

SSRS report wont work with a shared data source .
Report works perfectly fine if i use embedded data source.
The moment i switch back to shared data source the report goes blank again, no error shown.
I am trying to preview the report in visual studio 2013.
Any one got a similar problem? any suggested fix for this?

Comment: This is usually caused by security constraints. Is the shared dataset on the same machine as the report or on a server?

Comment: I tried using the exact same sql credentials for both shared and embedded data source, embedded works, shared dont work !!

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Sql server BI plugin update fixed the rendering issue